# Text in a horizontal nav bar (using ul and li) isn't vertically centered

Tags: html, css, navbar

**Update** After poking around a little more, I found a way to do it by replacing the `span` text with `div`, and setting this style:

```
.navItem div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

not sure if that's the best way though... everything feels messy

---

I have been trying to create this nav bar, but I'm having an issue where the text in it isn't exactly vertically centered:

[image]

```css
    .navBar {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        height:54px;
        background-color: #DADADA;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .navItem {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
        font-size: 14px;
        height: 54px;
    }
    
    .navItem a {
        display: block;
        height: 54px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: color .25s, background .25s;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .navItem img {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .navIcon {
        height: 34px;
        width: 34px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

```html
      <ul class="navBar">
        <li class="navItem">
          <a>
            <img class="navIcon" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/297/297562.svg">
            <span>About</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navItem">
          <a>
            <img class="navIcon" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/297/297562.svg">
            <span>Updates</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I am also aware that my CSS is probably really funny-looking.  It has pieces from at least 3 different sources on how to create a horizontal nav bar.

I had problems centering the icon in the bar, so what you can see is I just manually added padding to the icon to force it to the center.

`vertical-align: center` did nothing

Comment: Your snippet is not working problem because the address of the assets are wrong, if you could make a jsfiddle with all the proper assets maybe we could help ;)

Comment: I didn't think image isn't really relevant, just the size of it is all that matters right?

Comment: I updated it with some random SVG asset I found online ^^

Comment: Without looking at the complete working example (with the svg/complete html/css) it's hard to help. Elements affect each other. We need to see a complete working example in order to help.

Comment: I agree with you, however I believe in this the complete working example is not necessary.  If you just run the code snippet, you can see there the "About" and "Updates" text is still slightly **above** the vertical center of the entire `navBar` (you can tell by the gray background)

Comment: Dekel is right, we need the exact same font, font size, css libraries, svg assets. It's all relevant to layout problems.

Comment: You want them to be centered exactly in the middle of the svg files, right? And they are both the same height?

Comment: Yes centered exactly by the SVG

Comment: Updated again so maybe it's easier to see.  Navbar is the parent, and the text in the code snippet above isn't vertically centered within it, it's slightly above the middle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a cleaner version, both for the CSS and the HTML. There is no reason to use classes on inner items when you have a perfectly good selector (which probably should be an ID, but that's another issue) to base off of. It also uses variable sizing, so it will work even if people doesn't use exactly what you want them to use for zoom, sizing etc.

```css
.navBar {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        height:3.5em;
        background-color: #DADADA;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .navBar li {
        display: inline-block;
        color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
        font-size: 0.9em;
        margin: 0.2em;
    }
    
    .navBar li a {
        display: block;
        padding-left: 0.8em;
        color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: color .25s, background .25s;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .navBar li img {
        height: 2.5em;
        width: 2.5em;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
.navBar li span {
  line-height: 3.5em;
  margin-left: .5em;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="navBar">
        <li>
          <a>
            <img src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/297/297562.svg"><span>About</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <img src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/297/297562.svg"><span>Updates</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time answering, ended up taking a second look and agree, your solution is cleaner and makes more sense-- to me, at least

Answer (score 3):

If you do not float `li`, then you can do the `vertical-align` from them.

```css
.navBar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #DADADA;
  color: white;
  line-height: 54px;
  /* to set li in the middle*/
}
.navItem {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* here it does what you look for */
  line-height: 1.2em;
  /* reset line-height to a nomal value */
}
.navItem a {
  display: block;
  /* whatever display you want */
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
  text-align: center;
  /* why ? */
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color .25s, background .25s;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navItem img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* aside text */
}
.navIcon {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}
/* eventually */

.navItem a span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navBar">
  <li class="navItem">
    <a>
      <img class="navIcon" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/297/297562.svg">
      <span>About</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="navItem">
    <a>
      <img class="navIcon" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/297/297562.svg">
      <span>Updates</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="navItem">
    <a>
      <img class="navIcon" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/297/297562.svg">
      <span>display on span <br/>can be useful too</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Same, Without using line-height *( @PhiterFernandes )* but only a pseudo to set the initial 54px of height as stated in the question.

```css
.navBar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #DADADA;
  color: white;
}
.navBar:before {
  content: '';
  padding-top: 54px;
}
/* commun style */

.navBar:before,
.navItem,
.navItem img,
.navItem a span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navItem {
  color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
  font-size: 14px;
}
.navItem a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
  transition: color .25s, background .25s;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navIcon {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navBar">
  <li class="navItem">
    <a>
      <img class="navIcon" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/297/297562.svg">
      <span>About</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="navItem">
    <a>
      <img class="navIcon" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/297/297562.svg">
      <span>Updates</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="navItem">
    <a>
      <img class="navIcon" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/297/297562.svg">
      <span>display on span <br/>can be useful too</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the `line-height` style was exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: The problem with line-height is if you need multi line text, but it's widely used. I'd use flex though.

Comment: How could I use flex here?  I thought that `flex` just lets you essentially set an element to have a weight (for size) within a container

Comment: Flex allows you to center items using `align-content` and others

Comment: @PhiterFernandes yes it does, but it would not have helped the op to deal with vertical-align (grid is on its way too) , beside, notice the span holding 2 lines of text :) . Finally, remove the line-height properties , it still works without a set height ;)

Comment: Flex will allow you to vertical-align items. Either using `margin: auto;` or by doing `align-items: center; justify-content: center;`

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie i know how to use flex for quiet a while and display:table for over a decade and display:inline+zoom for IE 5-6 to do such layout for even more . Feel free to give an answer with the flexmodel  , **but when i see `vertical-align:center;` written in a question, i think that some basics can be taken care of first ;)** (also updated the answer without the line-height properties to avoid extra confusion)